# The given code is supposed to make the div title float to the top right, but shifts a few pixels when done so. Why is it shifting by itself?

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS. As a part of the course, I have to make a website with layout something like this:-
[image]

The layout is satisfied as a whole, but my code has issues regarding the div title(Top right). The  title part shifts a few pixels when I change its width and float it by using media queries. Something like this:-
[image]

Ideally it should like this  picture:-
[image]

Below is some part of my HTML and CSS code.

```
  <div class = "row">
        <section class = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" >
            <div class = "Chicken">
            <h2>Chicken</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>  
        </section>
        <section class = "col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class= "Beef">
            <h2>Beef </h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class = "col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class = "Sushi">
            <h2>Sushi</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

div>h2
{
    width: 230px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
    
    
}

div>p
{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    
}

.Chicken, .Beef, .Sushi
{
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: #FF0000;

}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    .col-lg-1 {
        width: 8.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-2 {
        width: 16.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-3 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    .col-lg-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 41.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-6 {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .col-lg-7 {
        width: 58.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-8 {
        width: 66.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-9 {
        width: 74.99%;
    }
    .col-lg-10 {
        width: 83.33%;
    }
    .col-lg-11 {
        width: 91.66%;
    }
    .col-lg-12 {
        width: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to add padding-top: 0 to the H2.

Comment: While it solved the problem for this margin, but if the margin is changed or if I resize the browser window it still shifts a few pixels, not from top but right side this time.